# PowerShell script to Open, Refresh and close excel file via web excel in SharePoint then download the file

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, powershell

I am using windows server 2016 and it does not have an MS-excel application.
But I have to Open refresh and close the excel file (The file is in SharePoint) via web excel in SharePoint and then download it on windows server 2016 so that the user can get the updated data.

Comment: I am new to SharePoint please help

Comment: According to your description, you are using SharePoint Server. Moreover, your computer does not have an office client. When the file is downloaded locally, it will not be updated synchronously with the one in SharePoint. Also, as far as I know, there is currently no way to do what you want using PowerShell.

Comment: I have downloaded the excel file to my server with the PowerShell script.

Comment: Now my question is, can we open, refresh and close the excel file in web-excel via PowerShell script?

Comment: You mean, you have downloaded the file to the windows server, right? If so, I think the next operation has nothing to do with SharePoint.